# Django Custom Pagination - setting as default in settings.py

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

**6.30.15 - HOW CAN I MAKE THIS QUESTION BETTER AND MORE HELPFUL TO OTHERS? FEEDBACK WOULD BE HELPFUL. THANKS!**

I have a custom pagination I need to set for my Django Rest Framework. I have created a pagination.py file and placed the pagination settings there under a class.

In Settings.py I have to point to it using the 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'. However, I can not get settings.py to find it. Even though I've specified the path. In the documentation I noticed there's a similar 'apps.core.pagination' path - **do I have to create this?** **Where do I need to place this so the settings.py can read it?**

```
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 
'XXXX_XX_api.static.rest_framework.pagination.CustomPagination'
```

UPDATE: 6.22.15 
I added the custom pagination to my settings file, but now I'm getting a weird error. And I'm not sure why. Everything seems to be correct in my code. In the error it reads the custom pagination but it says that pagination is not defined. Any thoughts?

```
 File "/home/dbadmin/epic_ar_api/epic_ar_api/epic_ar_api/pagination.py", line 5, in <module>
    class CustomPagination(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):
NameError: name 'pagination' is not defined
[22/Jun/2015 13:29:24] "GET /machines/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
^Cdbadmin@ubuntu:~/epic_ar_api/epic_ar_api$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` settings in the global `settings.py` file in the `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings dictionary.

Suppose my `CustomPagination` class resides in `pagination.py` file in `my_app` of `my_project`. Then i can do the following:

```
   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my_project.my_app.pagination.CustomPagination',
        'PAGE_SIZE': 100
    }
```

**# Update:**

Add the following line to your `pagination.py` file:

```
from rest_framework import pagination
```

This will import the default rest_framework pagination.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rahul! I appreciate the help. I've run into an issue though. Do you know what you be causing the error listed above?